# Electron : How to access webview inside a webpage which is rendered in the render process from the main process (toPrint , etc)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webview, electron, chromium

I am trying to fetch the reference of the **webview** that i have made available inside a webpage which is remotely hosted and i load this webpage inside my electron app.

As i need **webContents** instance to print silently , i want the webContents which refer to the **webview** inside the page.

Constraint here is , Print should be **Main Process** Driven and not handled by the Web Page on its own .

How can this be done ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now i am using a cheap dirty hack , sending the id of the webview to the main process and then using `webContents.executeJavascript` to execute the following script `document.getElementById("'+id+'").print(silent: true)` . Now atleast what to print is under the control of mainProcess . 
If anybody has a cleaner way to do this , please do let me know . 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Marking this the answer for time being till a better cleaner solution is found.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the webview and print its content from the renderer process.
First store the webview in a variable:

```
const webview = document.getElementById('webview');
```

then you can do:

```
webview.print({silent: true});
```

In the docs: https://electron.atom.io/docs/api/webview-tag/#webviewprintoptions

**Modification**

If you want to access the webContents from the main process instead, you can:

```
webview.getWebContents().send('print');
```

and in the main process:

```
ipcMain.on('print', (event) => {
  event.sender.webContents.print({silent: true});
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response , i know it can be done from the renderer process easily . But What i really wanted was that this print code should be in the code base of the main process instead of the renderer process .
For that i need the webview's reference in the main Process . Is this even possible ?

Comment: Ok, I got it. I will modify my answer.

Comment: check the modification and tell me if it worked for you

Comment: Sorry zied it did not work for me , in the modified case the print event of ipcMain is not even getting triggered. As per the docs webview.send events should be listened by the renderer process and it should in turn send it to the main process .